# How do I change the Title/Branding in navigation bar for Blazor WASM Identity pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor WASM project.
It is using authentication and to do so it navigates to it's own server side pages in the area Identity.
I have tried to scaffold these pages in order to change the title on the navbar but I cannot figure this out.

It currently shows the project name (i.e. BlazorApp.Server)

[navigation bar example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAFWQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to scaffold an Identity page to get access to `_Layout.cshtml`. I usually scaffold the Register and Manage/Index pages.
[image]

[image]

[image]

You will find the branding your after in there.

As a side note I change the style sheet it points to to site.css in the `wwwroot\css` folder

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/css/site.css" />
```

to

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```